# Separable extensions of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> F is a field that has no separable extensions. How to prove that any algebraic extension of F also has no separable extension?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $char(F)=p$. Show that we can assume $K/F$ is finite. If $K(a)/K$ is separable then let $p^n \ge [K:F]$ you'll have that $F(a^{p^n})/F$ is separable and $[K(a):K]\le [F(a^{p^n}):F]$

Comment: Thank you,but there is  a problem that the algebraic extension of F is not necessarily a  finite extension.